# shouldStartLoadWithRequest doesn't run stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I am trying to run the code below in webview's shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method but it doesn't make any changes.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    NSLog(@"webView shouldStartLoadingWithRequest");
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.execCommand('bold', false,null)"]];
    return TRUE;
}
```

There is no error, it prints the NSLog and **everything in the method works great except "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" method.**

But if I try to make text bold in another function, for example an IBAction method, works fine.

```
-(IBAction)boldClick:(id)sender
{
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.execCommand('bold', false,null)"]];
}
```

Actually, this is my company's special application and this UIWebView will not show the web pages. I am using it to show some custom HTML pages.
I need to make everything in "shouldStartLoadWithRequest" because I am trying to run an objective-c method from javascript.

**UPDATE**

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    // Break apart request URL
    NSString *requestString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    NSArray *components = [requestString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];


    // Check for your protocol
    if ([components count]==3)
    {
        [self makeBoldText];
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}

-(void)makeBoldText
{
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.execCommand('bold', false,null)"]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc says that method `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest`: is sent **before** a web view begins loading a frame. After you return YES in this method, web view starts loading a request. So any javascript you execute will have no effect, because a new page will be loaded **after** your JS call.

You can probably use `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method to execute javascript after page finishes to load. Or if you want to trigger JS by clicking on a link, you can use `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` but return NO from it.